# Push plugin notification for apache cordova android app using phonegap-plugin-push

Tags: cordova, firebase, visual-studio-2015, phonegap-pushplugin, apache-cordova

I have an android app built on apache cordova. I want push notifications for this application. I have used Visual studio 2015 IDE to built this application.
I have already installed some plugins for this application like cordova-plugin-device-orientation, statusbar etc. To enable push notifications for this app I have installed phonegap-plugin-push (version 2.1.0) and provided the sender Id for my application which I created using Firebase. By creating new project, added android app, downloaded google-services.json file and placed it in my project.

```js
<script>
        function setupPush() {
        //This line below throws error on simulator saying PushNotification //is not defined
            var push = PushNotification.init({
                "android": {
                    "senderID": "XXXXXXXXXX"
                },
                "ios": {
                    "sound": true,
                    "alert": true,
                    "badge": true
                },
                "windows": {}
            });
            alert('registered');
            push.on('registration', function (data) {
                alert('registration event' + data.registrationId);
                console.log("registration event: " + data.registrationId);
                var oldRegId = localStorage.getItem('registrationId');
                if (oldRegId !== data.registrationId) {
                    // Save new registration ID
                    alert('registration event' + data.registrationId)
                    localStorage.setItem('registrationId', data.registrationId);
                    // Post registrationId to your app server as the value has changed
                }
            });

            push.on('error', function (e) {
                console.log("push error = " + e.message);
            });
        }
       
        $(document).on('deviceready', function deviceIsReady() {
            console.log('Device is ready!');
            setupPush();
        });
    </script>
```

I found this code [here](http://macdonst.github.io/push-workshop-eu/module2.html).

Answer (score 0):

What is your cordova CLI and cordova platform android version?
I am using 6.2.3 android version and it run normally.

Please try to install the plugin first, after all the plugin install success than install the android platform for project.

Comment: cordova-cli: 6.1.1, "android": "5.1.1". My android app is already deployed on play store so the android platform is already installed can't change it now. Just want to add push notification service for my android app.

Comment: @Warda Your plugin version is not allow for 5.1.1, you must using 6.2.1 or higher, please take a reference in https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/INSTALLATION.md

Comment: have you build your apache cordova android app project in visual studio 2015?